# Is there a reason why IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CXF_190100_10032020_092100_01_1003202001.XML'

Tags: python, xml

Im trying to open a directory and parse xml file using xml.etree.ElementTree

Below is my code and the error i get:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

src = r'C:\\User\\Desktop\\TEST\\SampleFiles_xml\\test'
c = os.listdir(src)

for file in c:
    if file.endswith(".XML"):
        tree = ET.parse(file)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A186757\Desktop\TEST\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse(file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1183, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 647, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CXF_190100_10032020_092100_01_1003202001.XML'
```

Comment: Join the path and the filename!

Comment: Thanks but i get the error below when i do: for file in os.path.join(c, file)...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\User\Desktop\TEST\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    for file in os.path.join(c,file):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 73, in join
    elif isabs(b):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 57, in isabs
    s = splitdrive(s)[1]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 125, in splitdrive
    if p[1:2] == ':':
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I did import glob and works for me.